# Color Changing in Visual 2D Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently experimenting with 2D arrays. I can't think of a way at the moment to do this, but I want to be able to click one of the cells and have it change to the opposite color. To demonstrate, if I click a blue cell, I want it to turn red, and the opposite action if I click a red cell. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head><title>Visualizing 2D Arrays</title>
<style>
    #stage 
    {
        position: relative;
    }

    .cell
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
</head>



<body>
    <div id="stage"></div>
    <script>

        //Get a reference to the stage

        var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

        //The 2D array that defines the pattern
        var pattern =
        [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 1]
            ];

            //The sixe of each cell
            var SIZE = 30;

            //The space between each cell
            var SPACE = 10;

            //Display the array
            var ROWS = pattern.length;
            var COLUMNS = pattern[0].length;

            for(var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
                {
                    //Create a div HTML element called cell
                    var cell = document.createElement("div");

                    //Set its CSS class to "cell"
                    cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

                    //Add the div HTML element to the stage
                    stage.appendChild(cell);

                    //Make it black if it's a "1"
                    if(pattern[row][column] === 1)
                    {
                        cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    }

                    //Position the cell in the correct place
                    //with 10 pixels of space around it
                    cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
                    cell.style.left = column * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
                }
            }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just to simplify the problem, `else` condition is added where `blue` color is set to the element.

To have a click listener, `addEventListener` method of `node`/`element` is used. There are other ways to attach click listeners too. `addEventListener` expects second argument to be a callback function which is a function expression to be called once `click` event takes place on the event. `element.style.backgroundColor` will get/set the `backgroundColor` to the element.

```js
 var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

 //The 2D array that defines the pattern
 var pattern = [
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]
 ];

 //The sixe of each cell
 var SIZE = 30;

 //The space between each cell
 var SPACE = 10;

 //Display the array
 var ROWS = pattern.length;
 var COLUMNS = pattern[0].length;

 for (var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
   for (var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++) {
     //Create a div HTML element called cell
     var cell = document.createElement("div");

     //Set its CSS class to "cell"
     cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

     //Add the div HTML element to the stage
     stage.appendChild(cell);

     //Make it black if it's a "1"
     if (pattern[row][column] === 1) {
       cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     } else {
       cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
     }

     //Position the cell in the correct place
     //with 10 pixels of space around it
     cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
     cell.style.left = column * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
     cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
       this.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor == 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';

     });
   }
 }
```

```css
 #stage {
   position: relative;
 }
 .cell {
   position: absolute;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="stage"></div>
```